# How to show variable values right in the Python code in Spyder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

Is it possible to show variable values right in the Python code in Spyder like in Chrome Dev Tools:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280308/how-do-i-debug-efficiently-with-spyder-in-python

Comment: In pycharm debugger you can see

Comment: @DirtyBit thank you, but I didn't find the answer there

Comment: Akhilesh, what are the limits of free version of pycharm? Did you use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Spyder 3.3.1 and I use "Variable Explorer" window, when in debugging mode to watch the variables change. This is **the closest** feature to the behavior you are looking for (which I'm aware of...) It should look like this:

[image]

**EDIT**:

In Pycharm though, the current state of variables is represented, along the code lines, similar to what you get in Chrome Dev, but it is also triggered from debugging mode. Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: It is not what I'm asking

Comment: Thank you @Tim Mironov. I don't know why, but debugging is not working, when I hit play everything works fine but without variable values in code. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ECKL.png

Comment: @joys What version of PyCharm do you use? 
I have PyCharm Professional 2018.2

Comment: I use educational version 2018.3